# Populate a List of Double with String

Tags: java, spring, string, list, populate

I have a method which tests if a `List` of `Double` contains some `String` elements. This list is populated with Spring. I do not know how I can populate it with `String` in a JUnit.

My method converts `String` to `Double` with the following code:

```java
// [...]
Obect element = list.get(i); // list is my List<Double>
if(element.getClass() == String.class) {
   list.set(i, Double.parseDouble((String) element));
}
```

Comment: "if a List of Double contains some String elements" why would a `List<Double>` contain `String` elements? If that's not what you mean, please clarify.

Comment: Also: `element instanceof String` is a better way to check.

Comment: How did you declare your list? Are you using a raw type, or did you declare it as `List<Object>`?  because if you declared it as `List<Double>` getting a String inside that List would be quite hard.

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS it's not _that_ hard, it just indicates a broader issue that would be better to fix at source.

Comment: The comment say "Sometimes Spring instantiates a list of doubles with string element". It's not my code. I am only the guy who must write a JUnit for covering the code, even if it seems stupid for me. OH GOD SPIDERS, it's my question how can I declare a list like that, which is stupid, we are agree

Comment: `element instanceof String` will return false if `element` is null, whereas your code will throw `NullPointerException`.

Comment: Could you please show what your list looks like before and after processing.  Only a few items are required to show its diversity.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a `List<Double>` as you claim, then it is impossible to add a `String` to it, so it does not make sense to test it. Nevertheless, requirements are not always making a lot of sense. So, your code is almost correct, but there is a mistake to fix inside (as you have already known when you have written the question). Let's see a better code:

```
Obect element = list.get(i); // list is my List<Double>
if(element.getClass().equals(String.class)) {
   list.set(i, Double.parseDouble((String) element));
}
```

You need to use the `equals` method instead of the `==` operator, because the `==` operator checks whether the operands are the ***same***, yet, the `getClass` method creates a new instance of the `Class` class, which, by definition will not be the same as `String.class`. The `equals` method checks whether the two objects are similar. They are similar if the object is a `String`.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like this is what you want. This conditional converts the strings to Double objects or passes on the doubles.  It uses `Double.valueOf()` to avoid having to rebox the `double`.

I also prefer to simply create a new list. Inserting values as you are doing can cause quite a bit of copying (or counting if a linkedList).  Also using `instanceof` as suggested in the comments.

```
List<Object> list = Arrays.asList(
        2.3, 4.7, null,  "99.3", "47.2", null, 2.8, "48.7");
    

List<Object> result =
        list.stream().map(ob -> (ob instanceof String) ?
                Double.valueOf((String)ob) : ob).toList();

System.out.println(result);
```

Prints

```
[2.3, 4.7, null, 99.3, 47.2, null, 2.8, 48.7]
```

If you want just a list of Doubles then you would need to cast the last item in the ternary (?:) construct to double (e.g. `(Double)ob`). Filtering out any nulls may also be desirable.